# A file executed from crontab returns different results than from command line

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I need to run a script from crontab and this has a simple server load check that looks like this:

```
server_load=$(bash -c '/bin/more /proc/loadavg | 
              /usr/bin/cut -d" " -f1 | /usr/bin/cut -d"." -f1')
```

If I run the script from command line I get the server load, if I run it from crontab I get a strange and useless result.

I did look for posts with similar issues but nothing from what was suggested helped me solve my issue.

Comment: Why use `more` on `/proc/loadavg`?  Why not simply: `cut -f" " -f1 /proc/loadavg | ...`?  Does `more` work correctly when none of its standard I/O channels is a terminal (which is what happens when it is run from `cron`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That whole line could be simplified to:

```
server_load=`cut -d. -f1 /proc/loadavg`
```

I suspect that the problems are related to `more` wanting a terminal and thus emitting terminal control sequences.